# Issues reading many excel files

Tags: python

I'm reading many xls files with this code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

#reading the name of files
path = os.getcwd()
files = os.listdir(path)
files_xls = [f for f in files if f[-3:] == 'xls']

#creating empty dataframe
dfs = pd.DataFrame()

#reading and append xls files
for i in files_xls:
    data = pd.read_excel(i, 'Sheet 1',converters={'CODIGO':str})
    dfs = dfs.append(data)
```

With this code, I can read all the xls files with no problem.
But when I want to define the path, I get an error.

```
#reading the name of files
path = "/path/to/file"
files = os.listdir(path)
files_xls = [f for f in files if f[-3:] == 'xls']

#creating empty dataframe
dfs = pd.DataFrame()

#reading and append xls files
for i in files_xls:
    data = pd.read_excel(i, 'Sheet 1',converters={'CODIGO':str})
    dfs = dfs.append(data)
```

Error message:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Acobamba000659a.xls'
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably forgetting that `os.listdir()` returns just the file names, without the path. You might try this:

```
files_xls = [os.path.join(path, f) for f in files if f[-3:] == 'xls']
```

Answer (score 2):

`os.listdir` gives you file name not path.
you can use jurez solution or just use glob

```
import glob

dfs = pd.DataFrame()
path = "/path/to/file/*.xls"

for i in glob.glob(path):
    data = pd.read_excel(i, 'Sheet 1',converters={'CODIGO':str})
    dfs = dfs.append(data)
```